# Does models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) stay in code after creating tables?

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am working on a project built by some people before me, when I was creating some new tables using sqlalchemy I figured out that the method which creates tables were removed. So, I had to put it in code again to create tables. What I am wondering is if it doesn't need to stay in code after creating tables. is there any problem with keeping it there?

Here is the line code that I am talking about:

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Metadata.create_all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=create_all#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) takes a `checkfirst` keyword argument which determines whether SQLAlchemy should check whether a table already exists before trying to create it.  The default value of this argument is `True`, so once the tables have been created future invocations will have no effect, beyond emitting a few queries.

You can leave the code in place - it will be useful when a developer needs to create a fresh environment.